# Djangos m2m_changed trigger doesn't trigger properly

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model that looks as follows and I wish to trigger a method every time the user_ids field get's changed. Using the `post_save` signal obviously didn't do anything, as ManyToMany relationships are special in that way.

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_ids = models.ManyToManyField('user.User')
```

Using the `m2m_changed` trigger as follows also didn't do anything, which got me puzzled. I don't really understand what is wrong with this code also having tried to leave the '.user_ids' out. There are no errors or anything, it just doesn't trigger when the user_ids from the Lease model are changed.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Lease.user_ids)
def update_user_unit(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('Test')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed), I suppose the sender should be the intermediate model, not the ManyToMany field itself. Try this:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Lease.user_ids.through)
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to come back to you. This is actually what I was looking for, I tried this before but wondered why it always only does a certain thing, but now I realized that I need to use the action parameter to only trigger at certain events.